# Can I modify an app manifest and re-sign the SharePoint .app file?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, manifest, digital-signature

I am building a SharePoint 2013 provider-hosted app using the high-trust model.  This allows a customer to deploy the .app to their App Catalog and make it available to all SharePoint Sites.  The provider-hosted portion of the app runs in an IIS box (cluster) which the customer also deploys (on-premise) with setup instructions and automated tools.

The .app file structure includes the application manifest - which specifies the precise endpoint where the provider-hosted portion resides, and also specifies whitelisted endpoints which the add-in can call.  These are all specified by entering in URLs, hostnames, and port numbers into edit fields in Visual Studio in the 'Deploy App' form just before the .app file is built and digitally signed.

This seems to work just fine for a single app built by IT folks internally, if the org is small enough... but I really want to be able to distribute this solution to more than one customer. In order to do so, I would have to ask the customer for their respective endpoints, enter them into my build tools, and rebuild the .app for them.  This just doesn't seem right... no customer wants to talk to the developer first and have a custom-built app. And why should they? No code is changing...

Upon investigation into the .app file format, it turns out it is really just a simple .zip file - and inside (voila!) there is the app manifest! Unfortunately, if you edit the app manifest and re-zip the file, the digital signature is broken, and the .app no longer works. (grrrr...)

What I want to do is simply reconfigure the app manifest to match the environment where it is deployed. This can happen programmatically during setup/installation time, or perhaps even just prior to download, but cannot be a process that involves developers typing into visual studio and pressing Rebuild. That simply won't scale.

Is there a tool that exists that can help with this problem? If not, does anyone have experience with the signing of .app files programmatically? I'm open to skinning this cat in any way possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild idea and not maybe even possible.

1. Create web ui, where clients enter their endpoints.
2. Have internal process that invokes MSBUILD/TFS to package app with endpoint

   - change app manifest with pre-build powershell
3. Then provide app via email or download?

http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2013/10/building-sharepoint-2013-apps-with-tfs-2013/

Comment: Ah... that is an interesting approach. I'm not using TFS for this particular project, but I see how an MSBUILD command-line could be kicked off.  It might open up a DOS attack vector - so I'll have to defend against that of course... I'd like a solution that didn't necessarily call the build tools, but I see where you're going with this. It would be ideal if I could just re-sign the .zip file - but I don't see any documentation on how that could be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a true answer - but would work:

For on-premise deployments of high-trust SharePoint 2013 apps - build the application with "known endpoints" - essentially hard-coded endpoints that can be deployed locally. Then instruct the customer to redirect those endpoints using DNS records or `hosts` file entries.  In addition, the client would need to generate a local wildcard certificate signed by their own trusted root in order to satisfy the SharePoint 2013 app model requirements for appdomain and server-to-server communication.

This is by no means ideal, but for certain environments it might be the most practical approach. This also allows scaling for the IIS WebApp to occur at the customer-site, where it realistically belongs for a high-trust app.

This approach avoids the need to automate build tools and also avoids building a separate instance for every customer - both of which are somewhat undesirable. It might, for those reasons, be slightly less costly - but it also pushes some responsibility to the customer. Namely - hard-coding a DNS entry locally for machines in the topology.